# Не работает селект по атрибуту | JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

```js
$('*[redirect]').on('click', function() {
  let direct = this.getAttribute('redirect');
  console.log('redirect,', direct);
  // core.mount(direct);
});

$('*[click]').on('click', function() {
  let methodName = this.getAttribute('click');

  if (methodName.length > 0) {
    console.log('click,', methodName);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="header">
  <span redirect="main" click="name" class="font-monospace fst-normal text-center text-uppercase fs-4">${appName}</span>
  <span redirect="setting" class="icon position-absolute">${icons.setting}</span>
</div>
```

Странно то, что у меня находит элементы с [redirect], но совершенно не видит элементы с [click]. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну если убрать код с `*[redirect]`, то вообще консоль выводит все. Может у вас есть другие ошибки, которые блокируют дальнейшее выполнение метода? Например наличия переменной `core`?

Comment: Почему не используете валидные `data-`атрибуты или привязку к классам?

Comment: Добавил ваш код в snippet, здесь всё работает... ошибка где-то в другом месте (возможно в закомментированной строчке). К тому же `*[click]` звездочка означает "все элементы на странице", она лишняя (выбираются все элементы, у которых есть атрибут click), достаточно просто `[click]`. Это стандартные CSS-селекторы, а не фишка jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Звездочка зачем? Вообще, я бы более точный селектор на твоём месте выдумал  (тем более, если html твой)

```js
$('[redirect]').on('click', ({currentTarget, target})=>{
    const direct = currentTarget.getAttribute('redirect');
    const direct2 = target.getAttribute('redirect');
    console.log('redirect:', direct, direct2);
});

$('[click]').on('click', ({currentTarget, target})=>{
    const methodName = currentTarget.getAttribute('click');
    const methodName2 = target.getAttribute('click');
    console.log('click:', methodName, methodName2);
});
```

```css
span{background:gainsboro;padding:6px;border-radius:3px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="header">
    <span redirect="main" click="name" class="font-monospace fst-normal text-center text-uppercase fs-4">${appName}</span>
    <span redirect="setting" class="icon position-absolute">${icons.setting}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Обернул скрипт ready и заработало.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('[redirect]').on('click', function () {
        let direct = this.getAttribute('redirect');
        core.mount(direct);
    });

    $('[click]').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        let methodName = this.getAttribute('click');

        if(methodName.length > 0) {
            console.log(methodName);
        }
    });
});
```